# Using a toggleWidget in rgl with Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I have tried without success to create a toggle-able plot display using the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)

ui <- (fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("chk", label = "Display", value = TRUE),
  playwidgetOutput("control"),
  rglwidgetOutput("wdg")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))

  open3d()
  plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
  scene <- scene3d()
  rgl.close()

  plot3d(scene)

  output$wdg <- renderRglwidget({
    rglwidget(controllers = c("control"))
  })

  output$control <- renderPlaywidget({
    toggleWidget("wdg", respondTo = "chk",
                 ids = as.integer(names(scene$objects[1])))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With the current code setup, I get the following error:

```
Error: length(buttonLabels) == length(components) is not TRUE
```

From what I can tell about the way `toggleWidget` wraps `playwidget`, though, it seems like both `buttonLabels` and `components` are character vectors with a length of 1.

I have also tried a number of different variations for the `ids` variable of `toggleWidget` with similar levels of success.  Examples for `rgl` in Shiny seem to be few and far between.

What is the proper way to use a `toggleWidget` in `rgl` with Shiny?

Comment: You shouldn't be putting `toggleWidget` inside `renderPlaywidget`.  The latter is intended to hold a `playWidget` and nothing else.  However, I don't know  Shiny well enough to know what you should be doing instead.  How would you include html code?

Comment: I think my previous comment is wrong, sorry!  Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particular error message you are seeing was due to a bug in `rgl`:  when linked to a Shiny control, you needed to explicitly set the `toggleWidget` label to `character()`.  There was also another bug related
to the checkbox that Shiny uses.  Both bugs have been fixed.

However, this isn't enough to get your example to work.  I haven't fully debugged it, but I can see the following:

- You are plotting the scene twice.  You probably only want to plot it once.
- Since you've saved the scene in variable `scene`, you should pass that to `rglwidget()`.
- The safest way to get the ids to toggle is to save the result of the `plot3d` call, then use those values in the `toggleWidget` call.

I'm not sure which of these cause your script to fail, but the new `demo(shinyToggle)` (shown below) works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)

open3d(useNULL = TRUE)
ids <- plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100))[1]
scene <- scene3d()
rgl.close()

ui <- (fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("chk", label = "Display", value = FALSE),
    playwidgetOutput("control"),
    rglwidgetOutput("wdg")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
    save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
    on.exit(options(save))

    output$wdg <- renderRglwidget({
        rglwidget(scene, controllers = c("control"))
    })

    output$control <- renderPlaywidget({
        toggleWidget("wdg", respondTo = "chk",
                 ids = ids)
    })
}

if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Outstanding.  This works perfectly with `0.98.10`.  Thanks for the prompt bug fixes.